# how to load a form from php file dynamically based on option

Tags: php, html

here is the code:

```
<ul>

    <li><a id="various3" href="index2.html">Opera</a></li>
            <li><a id="various3" href="index2.html">Chrome</a></li>
</ul>
```

it is available in index2.html

```
<form id="browsers" name="form100" action="browser.php" method="post"> 

<li> Do you like look and feel of your browser?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="2"/> No

<li> Does your system gets slow when your browser is running?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="2"/> No
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="3"/> Maybe
<li> Does the browser load fast when you click on the icon?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="2"/> No
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="3"/> Maybe

<li> Does the images render fast in your browser?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="2"/> No

<li> Does video and image streaming fast in your computer?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="2"/> No

<li> Does every website load faster and properly in your browser?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q6" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q6" value="2"/> No

<li> Does your browser get slow when you open more than 3 tabs?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q7" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q7" value="2"/> No

<li> Does it needs inbuilt mp3 player?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q8" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q8" value="2"/> No

<li> Does it needs inbuilt flash player?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q9" value="1"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q9" value="2"/> No

<li> Does it needs inbuilt media player?<br/> 
<input type="radio" name="q10" value="1" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q10" value="2" /> No
<li> Whether your browser should be visually customizable? <br/> 

<input type="radio" name="q11" value="1" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q11" value="2" /> No</li> 
<li> Should your browser have twitter and Facebook integration?<br/> 

<input type="radio" name="q12" value="1" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q12" value="2" /> No</li> 
<li> Should your browser have chat application?<br/> 

<input type="radio" name="q13" value="1" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q13" value="2" /> No
</li> 
<li> Will you recommend this to a friend?<br/> 

<input type="radio" name="q14" value="1" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="q14" value="2" /> No
</li> 
<li id="com">Type in your comments<br/> 
<textarea name="comments" value="" cols=40 rows=6></textarea><br/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="I've verfied the above. Submit It!"><br/> 
</ul> 
</form>
```

when i run index.html file. it has two link Opera and chrome. on clicking both it goes to index2.html. that is fine..

now i need to dynamically load form. the index2.html contains 14 question. when opera in clicked that 1,3,4,5,6,7 questions to be loaded and when chrome is clicked the remaining quesitons should be loaded. instead of making two html file to do this. is there any way to load the form based on selected option using php????

Comment: yes there are a lot of ways. Have you tried something?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the same id (various3) on more than one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your links to

```
<li><a id="various3" href="index2.html?browser=opera">Opera</a></li>
 <li><a id="various3" href="index2.html?browser=chrome">Chrome</a></li>
```

then in index2 you can see the browser selected in the $_GET global

$_GET['browser']

then you can go

```
if ($_GET['browser']=='opera'){
//whatever
}
```

Comment: how to load a form from php file??? only selected question from list of quesion??